# ASP.NET Ajax doesn't work in FF and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-7, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use asp.net 3.5 site with some ajax control toolkit elements. And it works fine in IE, but doesn't work in FF and Chrome.

In FF it says error:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; GTB7.3; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E) Timestamp: Thu, 7 Jun 2012 14:14:24 UTC
>
> Message: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load. Line: 98
>   Char: 34 Code: 0 URI: http://beta2.site.com/page.aspx
>
> Message: 'Sys' is undefined Line: 129 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://beta2.site.com/page.aspx

I use IIS7 web server.

What it could be? Who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It were not right values in web.config file.

should be for me:

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: To help the readers, what exactly was the problem that you fixed?